# Remove empty line after subesction

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I would like to redefine subsections so that there is no empty line afterwards, only a new line, e.g.

```
Subsection name
bla bla bla
```

I have tried the

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
 \@startsection{subsection}{2}%
      {)mm}%
      {\baselineskip}%
      {afterskip values}%
      {\normalfont\large\bf}}
\makeatother
```

with several values, but I only seem to be able to get either an empty line or no linebreak at all

Answer (score 6):

`article` defines subsection as

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

the skip after is `1.5ex \@plus .2ex` that is between 1.5 and 1.7 ex depending on the page contents. You can make that as small as you like but keep it > 0 otherwise you flag that you want a run in heading so `{1sp}` is as small as you can go.

Comment: thanks a lot! seems like i can not have the subsection start at the line exactly below its title :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that comment, TeX does not have any "lines" to which it fits text so the text after the title is the line below the title. Different font sizes have different preferred baselineskip but since the font size for the heading is different than the font size for the text there is no natural "line" distance. So you are free to make it whatever you wish. (1sp is the same as 0 unless you have an atomic microscope to hand so the fact that you need to set it to at least 1sp should not worry you

Comment: (If it does worry you of course it is possible to redefine the latex section commands to always linebreak, but it really is not worth it for a change that may make _no_ difference at all in the printed document when you consider the printer resolution)